# With CSS, can I set multiple backgrounds from different classes?

Tags: css

I know that it is possible to make multiple background layers with CSS, but can I layer multiple backgrounds coming from different classes?
Say I had divs acting as tiles that could have mountains or hills and could belong to a certain country.

```
.mountain {
    background: url("mountain.png");
}
.hill {
    background: url("hill.png");
}
.bluecountry {
    background: url("bluecountry.png");
}
.redcountry {
    background: url("redcountry.png");
}
.greencountry {
    background: url("greencountry.png");
}
```

would be my css. However, this doesn't work; when I do something like

```
<div class="hill bluecountry">
```

it will not layer the backgrounds, and will only use one of them.
Is there any way to make this work? I actually have more stuff than this, and it would be a huge waste of time to have to individually write CSS multiple backgrounds for every possible combination.

Comment: I still wonder how exactly you imagine the end result would look like. How would the "layers" look? Are they blended together somehow? What do you have in mind?

Comment: Each image only actually takes up part of the space and the rest of the image is transparent, it would just allow only certain parts of the background to change essentially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to merge the `background` attribute using multiple classes -- it can only be set once.  What you could do is:

1. create a container div (`position: relative`)
2. place multiple divs inside the container (`position: absolute`)
3. apply a separate class to each sub-div
4. The images can each be positioned within the container by using `top: 0px; left: 0px;`, and with `background-position`.

Here's an example of what I mean:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
div { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 100px; 
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.first, .second {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.first { 
    background: url(http://picsum.photos/200/100/?random=1) no-repeat; 
}
.second { 
    background: url(http://picsum.photos/200/100/?random=2) no-repeat; 
    background-position: right center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chriskorosu/z269x0oc/1/

Comment: I have a lot of these, so I used a negative margin instead, but overlap idea works well.

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option:

```js
$(".mountain, .hill, .bluecountry").each(function () {
  var backgrounds = [];
  if ($(this).hasClass("mountain"))
    backgrounds.push("url('mountain.png')");
  if ($(this).hasClass("hill"))
    backgrounds.push("url('hill.png')");
  if ($(this).hasClass("bluecountry"))
    backgrounds.push("url('bluecountry.png')");
  $(this).css("background", backgrounds.join(", "));
});
```