# Defining background gradient in one class and background image in another?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following chunk of CSS to define a gradient that is being applied to a number of different background images:

```
.myDiv{
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 28%), url(myimage.png);
}
```

The issue is that I have about 10 divs that will use this gradient.  Is there a way to define the gradient in one class and the background in another so that my code isn't so verbose?  I tried:

```
.myGradient{
   background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 28%);
}
.myDiv{
    background-image: url(myimage.png);
}
```

And then applying both classes to my div, but to no avail.  Is it possible to separate the gradient css from the image url?

Comment: Sounds similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665634/with-css-can-i-set-multiple-backgrounds-from-different-classes). In short there is no direct way. You could also have a look at some pre-processors like Less which can help with the merge syntax but the compiled CSS would still be as big.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it not possible to separate these because gradient and image are both `background-image` values. One or other will override other if you use them in different classes.

In my opinion, the other way will be to have a sprite of the gradient+image together using some photo editing tools and use them in 10 div by playing around with background-position.

Another way is to use `pseudo` classes like this:

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    background-size:cover;
}
div:after {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01) 28%);
    ;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.div1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/1/);
}
.div2 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/2/);
}
.div3 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/3/);
}
.div4 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/4/);
}
.div5 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/5/);
}
.div6 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/6/);
}
.div7 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/7/);
}
.div8 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/8/);
}
.div9 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/9/);
}
.div10 {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/10/);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
<div class="div5"></div>
<div class="div6"></div>
<div class="div7"></div>
<div class="div8"></div>
<div class="div9"></div>
<div class="div10"></div>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/738/

Comment: Would it be possible to use two layered bg images like this: ` background-image: <gradient values here>, url(<path to wanted image>) ; `?

Comment: Yes, you can have a look at the demo

Answer (score 0):

A bit of topic - but maybe interesting enough...

If you work with less (>= v1.5.0), you can use [property merging with the plus operator](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature).

At the end it's the same, CSS is not providing such a feature (I think).